# Initiating editing on a PropertyGrid

Tags: .net, winforms, focus, propertygrid

I'm looking for a good way to programmatically initiate editing on a System.Windows.Forms.PropertyGrid.  I can select the GridItem that I want, but that doesn't move the cursor into the edit field.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try sending the TAB key?

```
private void propertyGrid_SelectedGridItemChanged(object sender, SelectedGridItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
}
```